# windows phone 8.1 XAML TAGs encapsulation

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, binding, windows-phone-8.1

**BACKGROUND**

I'm learning MVVM for Windows Phone 8.1 with XAML.
To consolidate the knowledge, I started to make a simple calculator project.
As for buttons TextBlock used in the design, I learned to make binding to iCommand objects with Interaction.Behaviors as I show below:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="9" Style="{StaticResource calcButton}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalcCommand}" CommandParameter="9" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="4" Style="{StaticResource calcButton}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalcCommand}" CommandParameter="4" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="5" Style="{StaticResource calcButton}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalcCommand}" CommandParameter="5" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

Leaving a clean backXAMLcode where only instantiate the datacontext.
All TextBlock call the same command with different parameter.
The problem is that a calculator has many buttons, repeat the same pattern makes a big ugly XAML.

**QUESTION**

Somehow you know a way to encapsulate tags ...

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalcCommand}" CommandParameter="5" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

... in a similar way as we can encapsulate the style or otherwise?

```
Style="{StaticResource calcButton}"
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not use a `Button`?  It seems the more appropriate control, and would get rid of all the attached Event triggers. Just bind the `Command` and `CommandParameter` properties.

Comment: Create a UserControl with a single public property that you map to the command parameter of the internal binding.  Done.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Willem van Rumpt, the purpose of this project was to learn to use MVVM+VMBase+DelegateCommand+..., I also thought about using a button when I got 

to commands issue bu0t:
- I started using XAML labels, thinking it could easily associate commands to achieve the same visual effect with buttons would have had to modify many attributes of the button controller.
- If I had thrown in the towel, using buttons, I had not learned to bind any command to any controller.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Will, not thought, would be the right solution, although I will not use it because this project was to learn.

Comment: I have seen on the net that also exist macros for XAML:
http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/XAML_MarkupExtension_as_a_Macro_and_Object_Factory
Although I do not think they can serve this case.